# FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libopus.so'

Tags: python, discord.py

Python 3.9
OS : WIN10

I'm trying to create a discord bot that play a song
But it doesn't work after changing the compiler from Visual Studio 2022 to PyCharm
I tried a lot but it didn't work
Please help me

My code is:

```
import discord
import youtube_dl
from discord.ext import commands

token = "PRIVATE"

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if client.voice_clients == []:
        await channel.connect()

    if not discord.opus.is_loaded():
        discord.opus.load_opus('libopus.so')
```

Error Message :

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\discordbot\main.py", line 29, in play
discord.opus.load_opus('libopus.so')

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'libopus.so' (or one of its dependencies). Try 
using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

Comment: I think the library `libopus.so` does exist in your machine. Could you check if the library exist by using the code `from ctypes.util import find_library; print(find_library("libopus.so"))` to see if the library is printed out?

Comment: Also could you check if opus is loaded by checking if `discord.opus.is_loaded()` return `True`. If it does, then there is no need to call the method `discord.opus.load_opus('libopus.so')`

Comment: @taxevader Then, how can I install the library?

Comment: Have you installed `discord.py` or `discord.py[voice]`? See the [Docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) for more information on this.

Comment: @Dominik I already installed discord.py & discord.py[voice]

Comment: Is the code returns `True` for `discord.opus.is_loaded()`? I don't think there's a need to load the `libopus.so` on Windows

Comment: @taxevader I'm sorry to see your comment late.  As you said windows didn't need `libopus.so`.   Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JYS If the question is resolved, please post an answer! This will help others who may encounter the same problem in the future :)